# Java MySQL select where binary

Tags: java, mysql, select, hash, where-clause

I have a MD5 hash stored as binary(16) in the mysql database, i receive a hash in the app as a byte[].

How can i do a query with binary data??

```
private boolean isDuplicated(byte hash[]) throws SQLException {
        ResulSet st = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from IDENT where hash = "+ "???");
        return st.next();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a `PreparedStatement` with `setBytes`?

Comment: You should be using PreparedStatement and let the JDBC driver bind variables for you.  Your way is ripe for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mureinik and @duffymo

```
private int isDuplicate(byte hash[]) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement stament = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id_report from IDENT where hash = ?");
    stament.setBytes(1,hash);

    ResultSet st = stament.executeQuery();
    return st.next();
}
```